# How to extract particular values using regex in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, correlation, load-testing

Req body

```
Columnid:0:listid:0:productid:1 = off
Columnid:1:listid:3:productid:7 = off
Columnid:2:listid:7:productid:14 = off
```

For that first row I have 10 ids (1 to 10)

Regular expression is:

I have used below the expression

```
Checked = "checked" Columnid:(.+?):listid:(.+?):productid:(.+?)
```

I have kept Match no :  -1

I have passed the values like,

```
${col_1_g1}, ${list_1_g2}, ${prod_1_g3}
${col_2_g1}, ${list_2_g2}, ${prod_2_g3}
${col_3_g1}, ${list_3_g2}, ${prod_3_g3}
```

Product ID not takes only one number but it takes full value like productid:3:value="test"

PS: it does not take checked checkbox value(it takes full

I need to extract column id, listid, product id passing to respective request body

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a comprehensive response you need to provide:

1. At least partial HTML code containing the values you want to correlate
2. The desired next request body

in current state your question doesn't make a lot of sense as it's impossible to guess what you're trying to achieve. Check out documentation on [question markup formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

The only piece of advice I can provide so far is reconsider using regular expressions for parsing HTML, JMeter comes with [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor) and [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) which can pull the whole HTML [Form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) (or multiple [inputs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) with values) from the previous response.